# No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I'm running CQL3 with Cassandra 2.1.2, and here's what happens (I have a keyspace called default):

```
cqlsh> CREATE TABLE default.test (x int, y int) PRIMARY KEY (x);
cqlsh> CREATE TABLE default.test (x int PRIMARY KEY, y int);
cqlsh> INSERT INTO default.test (x, y) VALUES (1, 2);
cqlsh> INSERT INTO default.test (x, y) VALUES (1, 0);
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM default.test WHERE x=1 AND y > 1;
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator"
```

What happened? I read the related questions on here and they said I could have a > filter on the non-primary key as long as I had an = filter on the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are a few things going on here, so I'll tackle them one at a time.

1. Your first `CREATE TABLE` statement is not syntactically correct.

-

```
CREATE TABLE default.test (x int, y int) PRIMARY KEY (x);
```

Your PRIMARY KEY definition needs to be inside of your column definition, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE default.test (x int, y int, PRIMARY KEY (x));
```

Ironically, this is close to what you need to support your query.

2. PRIMARY KEYS in Cassandra are unique.  This becomes apparent when I follow your steps above and `INSERT` two rows:

-

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO default.test (x, y) VALUES (1, 2);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO default.test (x, y) VALUES (1, 0);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROm test;
x | y
---+---
1 | 0

(1 rows)
```

As `x` is your only PRIMARY KEY, the values of x = 1 and y = 2 are `INSERT`ed first...and then next `INSERT` promptly overwrites `y` with the value of 0.  And not only are PRIMARY KEYS unique, `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s are treated the same by Cassandra.

3. Ironically, the solution to support your query is the same as the solution to support both rows.

> I read the related questions on here and they said I could have a > filter on the non-primary key as long as I had an = filter on the primary key.

Not entirely true.  You are allowed to filter by > or < only on clustering columns, and then only if the partition key is restricted by equals.  As you have a single PRIMARY KEY, `x` is your partition key, and you *do not have a clustering column defined*.  Therefore to support this query, `y` must also be defined as part of the PRIMARY KEY, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE default.test (x int, y int, PRIMARY KEY (x,y));
```

Including `y` as a part of your PRIMARY KEY also helps to ensure uniqueness, which will allow your table to contain two rows:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO default.test (x, y) VALUES (1, 2);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO default.test (x, y) VALUES (1, 0);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROm test;
x | y
---+---
1 | 0
1 | 2

(2 rows)
```

With all of that done, this will now work:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM test WHERE x=1 AND y > 1;

 x | y
---+---
 1 | 2

(1 rows)
```

Here is a link to the most-recent doc detailing the CQL [SELECT](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html) statement.  You should definitely give that a read, a well as this one that explains [Compound Keys and Clustering](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html).